# How to enter symbol consisting of 4 points

Tags: symbols

I am reading *Elementary Topology Problem Book* O. Viro, et al. I came across to this curious symbol (which I have annotated in the screenshot below):

[image]

Is it possible to type this symbol in TeX? I am asking because I am currently taking notes while studying from this book, and it would be great if I could type the exact symbol as shown.

Comment: If you like, draw it in a separate program (not my strong point) in a TeX-friendly format, and create a command to include it as needed (e.g., `\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{<image>.png}`).

Comment: Ask Viro for the tex code for his book.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could create your own symbol using `tikz` and adjust the parameters as desired:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `baseline=0.25ex` was used to shift the symbol below the baseline.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\CircleSize}{0.6pt}%
\newcommand{\MySymbol}{\mathbin{\tikz [x=0.5em,y=1.4ex,line width=.2ex, baseline=0.25ex] %
    \draw [line width=0.4pt, fill=black] 
            (0.60,0.75) circle (\CircleSize) --
            (0.30,0.0) circle (\CircleSize) --
            (0.00,0.5) circle (\CircleSize) --
            (0.00,1.1) circle (\CircleSize)
    ;}}%
\begin{document}
We denote the space of the Problem by $\MySymbol$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The top edge on the left branch seems to be slanted. Or is it just an optical illusion?

Comment: the symbol in the original example has a depth that looks to be just a bit lower than the descender on "y".  this drawing sits on the baseline.

Comment: Why is the symbol in math mode?

Comment: @Marienplatz: In my version it is slanted (for some reason that is what I thought was required). But if you replace the last `0.10` with `0.00` it won't be slanted.

Comment: @gerrit: It does not need to be -- that is just how I prefer my symbols (as they are almost always in math mode).

Comment: @Marienplatz: Have corrected the left edge in the revised version.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Good point. Have adjusted the positioning.

Comment: I also think that the symbol should perhaps be typeset in math mode. But shouldn't it be a `\mathord`?

Answer (score 10):

How about making the symbol of your own (called `\myownsymbol`) where you may want to move it vertically by raisebox technique (here opt is set for the baseline). This is inspired by [How do I define a new punctuation mark?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136415/34618). (Thanks to those authors.)

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[papersize={15cm,4cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\mysymbol{%
\tikz{%
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=0.5pt] (A) at (0,0){};
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=0.5pt] (B) at (-2pt,3pt){};
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=0.5pt] (C) at (-2pt,6pt){};
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=0.5pt] (D) at (2pt,4pt){};
\draw (D)--(A)--(B)--(C);
}
}
\newsavebox{\mysymbolbox}
\savebox{\mysymbolbox}{\mysymbol}
\newcommand{\myownsymbol}{\raisebox{0pt}\kern1pt \usebox{\mysymbolbox}\kern-2pt}}

\begin{document}

\vspace{5cm}

This is my own symbol\myownsymbol.

We denote the space of Problem 2.3 (1) by \myownsymbol. It is a sort of toy space made of 4 points.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

The **exact** symbol with PSTricks just for fun!

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tree}

\def\icon#1{%
\psscalebox{#1}{%
\psTree[treemode=U,levelsep=1]{\TC*}
    \psTree{\TC*}
        \TC*
    \endpsTree
    \psTree[levelsep=.5]{\Tn}
        \TC*
    \endpsTree
\endpsTree}}

\begin{document}
Problem \textit{2.3} (1) by \icon{.15}.
\end{document}
```

[image]